# Python sorting a file by frequency

Tags: python, file, sorting, int, string

I have a file that contains a list of words like:

word1 34

word2 12

word3 6

word4 498

word5 50

I want to sort the file by the numerical value. My code:

```
sortedfreqlist = sorted(freqlist, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Doesn't quite work because it sorts the numbers as words i.e 12 comes before 6 etc.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting is not working because your values are not of a numeric type, thus lexicographic sorting is applied. Be sure to convert your sort key to to a number, for example like this:

```
sortedfreqlist = sorted(freqlist, key=lambda item: int(item[1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution if all items in the second column can be interpreted as ints.  I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Search "[natural sort python](http://www.google.com/search?q=natural+language+sort+python)" in your favorite search engine and you'll find many different solutions.

Here is one at [activestate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/285264-natural-string-sorting/).

Here is a nice [tidy solution at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort).